# CCK to Fields: content_migrate says missing widgets (image, matrix), but modules enabled

Tags: 7, migrations, entities, media

I am attempting an update from D6 to D7 on a site with multiple CCK types (yes, optimist me after reading lots of horror stories), I am following the CCK migration guide and have installed the cck module for D7. When accessing admin/structure/content_migrate to migrate cck to fields, I get the following warnings for all image and matrix type fields.

This looks like a bug in the migration code, but where to report to, CCK content_migrate, image or matrix module?

This is somewhat urgent as it affects the migration from d6 - d7 so I would be very grateful for any pointers.

### Details below:

> ```
> field_image   image   
> RNAi
> Changed field type: The 'field_image' field type will be changed from 'filefield' to 'image'.
> Missing widget: The 'image' widget is not available for the field_image field, it will be set to the default widget.
> ```

Edit: the same for the matrix module: "Missing widget: The 'matrix' widget is not available for the field_primer_group field, it will be set to the default widget."

But the image and matrix modules are both enabled:

```
 Core        Image (image)                      Module  Enabled   7.41
Fields       Matrix Field (matrix)              Module  Enabled   7.x-2.4
```

-- php is 5.3.3 (centos) and postgres is 8.4 if that matters.

Comment: Tumbleweed.... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can ignore the warning, it does not influence display or upload of images.